# KStream fails with "Could not create internal topics"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams

I am creating a KStream with a single thread and I get this error

```
Could not create topic: test-kstream-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-repartition 
due to org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: 
KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/topics/test-stream-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-repartition
```

Here is full stackTrace

```
Exception in thread "test-kstream-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create internal topics.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:89)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor.prepareTopic(StreamPartitionAssignor.java:675)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamPartitionAssignor.java:412)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:362)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:520)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:472)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:455)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:808)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:788)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:506)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:353)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:268)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:174)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:364)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1138)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1103)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:851)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:808)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
```

Version used
    Kafka Cluster that I'm connecting to 0.10.1.0
    kafka-streams version 1.0.0

There is no authentication required for the brokers that I am trying to connect to. Not sure what this exception means. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the broker configuration, especially the value for the `auto.create.topics.enable` entry?

Comment: @ValBonn that seems to be the issue. It is set to false.

Comment: @ValBon I can see here that the internal topics are follow a certain naming convention https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#internal-topics. Do you know if i can create these topics beforehand and use them in my kstream?

Comment: `auto.create.topics.enables` should not related to this issue. In fact, it highly recommended to _not_ enable it! -- However, it seems that the error originates from Zookeeper. You should check credentials for Zookeeper. `Do you know if i can create these topics beforehand and use them in my kstream?` -> yes, that would be possible (if the topic exists, it will be used).